# How to outline multiple states?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I am creating an interactive geo heatmap dashboard. Take the figures below as an example. The 1st plot is the output. How can I outline multiple states like shown in the 2nd plot? I going to divide USA state into 10 divisions, and create a drop down menu to select and show specific division.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'], # Spatial coordinates
    z = df['total exports'].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
    locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    colorbar_title = "Millions USD",
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State',
    geo_scope='usa', # limite map scope to USA
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t believe there is a straightforward way to do this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do something close to what you need using what you have here. I recognize that this solution is not exactly what you are looking for since the boundaries between states within the area in question are shown in my answer.  However, it is the closest to what you're looking for that I can think of how to do without calling other packages or tools. Hopefully it will help you figure out a more complete solution.

The basic idea behind this is that I'm adding a layer with the selected states, setting their alpha to 0, and then setting the state boarder to a given color.  My thought is that there may be a way to use the color mapping against the location data to overcome the issue of the lines appearing

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'], # Spatial coordinates
    #locations=['VA'],
    z = df['total exports'].astype(float), # Data to be color-coded
    locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    colorbar_title = "Millions USD",
    marker_line_color='white',   # will still work if you put this back in black
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State',
    geo_scope='usa', # limit map scope to USA
)

# to add these outlines"
# add layer of states to highlight
# turn their texture alpha to 0
# set their marker_line_color to a nice Blue
# and turn off the scale
chorpleth = go.Choropleth(
        locationmode='USA-states',
        z=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        locations=['ND','SD','NE','KS','MO','IA','MN','WI','MI','IL','IN','OH'],
        colorscale = [[0,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'],[1,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']],
        marker_line_color='Blue',
        showscale = False,
    )

fig.add_trace(chorpleth)

fig.show()
```

[image: map with selected states outlined]

Other solutions I can think of involve using [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html), so I'll look into something along those lines since this is admittedly partial.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is the closest to what I need without calling other packages or tools. Love your solution.